# Pandas Dataframe consumes too much memory. Any alternatives?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

Despite following best practices for reducing Pandas Dataframe object memory usage, I still find that the memory usage is too high. I've tried chunking, converting dtype, reading less data...etc.

For example, even though the CSV file I'm reading in is 2.7 GB large, when I use pd.read_csv, task manager shows that 25 GB of RAM have been used. I've tried converting objects to category, but some columns are not suitable for the conversion so object data type is the only choice I have.

Anyone have advice for how to reduce the memory usage, or alternative python libraries to use for low memory consuming dataframe objects? I've tried PySpark but the lazy evaluation is killing me every time I want to run a simple show statement.

Comment: Alternative to Pandas: [Vaex](https://vaex.io/) or [Dask](https://dask.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use [Dask dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html):

- [Common Uses and Anti-Uses](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html#common-uses-and-anti-uses)
- [Best Practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html)

> Dask DataFrame is used in situations where Pandas is commonly needed,
> usually when Pandas fails due to data size or computation speed.

> For data that fits into RAM, Pandas can often be faster and easier to
> use than Dask DataFrame. While “Big Data” tools can be exciting, they
> are almost always worse than normal data tools while those remain
> appropriate.